# Desktop icons on left screen go down into black hole

Tags: bash, multiple-monitors, desktop-environments, window-manager, desktop-icons

This is a self-answered question. See my answer below.

Here is my multi-monitor configuration:

```
$ xrandr --current | grep " connected"
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
```

A GUI view of the monitor setup is:

[image: resize1.png]

Previously Desktop Icons on Sony TV monitor wrapped properly:

```
+---------+  +---------+  
| Icon 1  |  | Icon 7  |  
+---------+  +---------+  
| Icon 2  |  | Icon 8  |  
+---------+  +---------+  
| Icon 3  |  | Icon 9  |  
+---------+  +---------+  
| Icon 4  |  | Icon 10 |  
+---------+  +---------+  
| Icon 5  |  | Icon 11 |  
+---------+  +---------+  
| Icon 6  |
+---------+
```

After the Toshiba TV was purchased the second column of icons has disappeared and column 1 is truncated:

```
+---------+
| Icon 1  |
+---------+
| Icon 2  |
+---------+
| Icon 3  |
+---------+
| Icon 4  |
+---------+
| Icon 5  |
+---------+
| Icon 6  |
+---------+
| Icon 7  |
```

Although the Sony TV is 1080 pixels high, when combined with Toshiba TV bottom right Laptop Display (another 1080 pixels) the desktop manager appears to use 4320 **virtual pixels** for placing the icons.

How can I place icons on Desktop using monitor size and not virtual screen size?

Sometimes I watch full screen videos on left monitor, how can I place icons to any monitor like the Toshiba TV?

Although a Python script could solve the problem, I prefer a bash solution because I'm more comfortable modifying bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## iconic

The problem was solved by creating the [iconic bash script](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) to place icons by monitor dimensions rather than virtual screen dimensions.

### iconic Main Menu

The main menu allows you to save and load desktop icon settings. The main menu leads you to additional windows to sort icons and manage monitors. Also you can apply new settings.

#### iconic Main Menu screenshot

[image: iconic main menu.png]

---

### iconic Sort Icons

You can sort icons alphabetically, or alphabetically by removing "Link to" from sort order. You can sort by date in ascending or descending order. After sorting you can reposition an individual icon to a higher or lower position.

#### iconic Sort Icons screenshot

[image: iconic sort icons.png]

---

### iconic Monitors Notebook

The notebook provides multiple tabs for accessing Monitors General settings and a tab for each individual monitor. Up to three monitors are currently supported.

The General settings tab allows you to set the monitor where desktop icons are placed. Additionally global definition of reserved space on left, top, right and bottom of monitors where icons should not go. Use this to reserve space for window manager launchers and application indicator bars.

#### iconic Monitors Notebook General Tab screenshot

[image: iconic monitors general.png]

On this notebook tab you can also specify the number of seconds a test will last. Press the <kbd>Test</kbd> button to place icons on the Desktop after you change reserved screen space.

#### iconic Monitors Notebook Monitor 3 tab

[image: iconic monitors monitor 3.png]

Assign a user friendly name to each monitor. Set the number of rows and columnss to utilize for icon placement on each monitor.

Use the <kbd>Test</kbd> button to view what icon placement after number or columns or rows are changed.

---

### Test button example

When you click the **Test** button all windows minimize and Icons are displayed exactly as they would appear on the Desktop if the current settings were implemented. After a number of seconds the Icons and Windows are restored as they were before the test.

[image: iconic 9 optimized.gif]