# Three monitor alignment with xrandr - I want one monitor left of *both* others

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have a three monitor setup. Call the monitors Above, Below, and Left.
When I move my mouse off the left of the screen of Above, I would like it to enter monitor Left.
I would like the same behavior with Below - when I move my mouse off the screen of Below, it should also enter monitor Left.

Finally, when I move my mouse off the top of the screen of Below, it should enter Above, and when I move my mouse of the bottom the screen of Above, it should enter Below.

Is this setup possible with `xrandr`/`arandr`?
I can use `arandr` to place Left to the left of Above,Below, overlapping both screens - but if my mouse is too far down on the Below screen, or too far up on the Above screen, it does not enter the Left screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change monitor position/navigation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10703/how-to-change-monitor-position-navigation)

Comment: No. This is specifically about a difficulty encountered only with *three* monitors. With two monitors it's easy for me to move the mouse from the right monitor to the left monitor. Here, I'm asking in particular about being able to move off the left side of the screen of *either of two* monitors, from *any part of the screen*. Using GUI tools to position the Left monitor allows me to reach it from the bottom half of the top screen, or the top half of the bottom screen, but not from any part.

Comment: Afraid you will have to move mouse from bottom to top and then to left. I've been doing this for six months myself.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix note that you can use the `arandr` gui to place the left monitor such that you can reach it from the top half of the lower monitor and the bottom half of the upper monitor, which is a little easier, but still not ideal

Comment: @yoyoy You can do that with regular system settings too. I used to have such a configuration as well at one time.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup. You can see yours with System Settings, but I have a python program that does it for me graphically (plus a lot more of course):

[image: mmm.png]

There are three monitors:

- HDMI-0 (1920x1080, upper left)
- DP-1-1 (3840x2160, upper right)
- eDP-1-1 (1920x1080, lower right)

The light-grey area of the canvas is where the mouse pointer cannot go. You can move portions of a window into the no-go area as you can see on HDMI-0. Sometimes the entire window can move to no-go area due to a bug in which case you can only recover with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (switch window) followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (move window) followed by mouse movement until it appears on a monitor.

Indeed if you were to put the icons on the top left monitor and select "Align Icons" many would paint down into the no-go area and [you won't be able to select them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146175/desktop-icons-on-left-screen-go-down-into-black-hole). Unless you used the answer in the link.